# Proxy bandwidth to / from backend server

Tags: nginx, lua, reverse-proxy, openresty

I am using NGINX with the OpenResty framework.

I have a server acting as a reverse proxy between users and multiple sites. I am interested in logging 4 different types of bandwidth use.

- Bytes from users to proxy
- Bytes from proxy to users
- Bytes from proxy to site server
- Bytes from site server to proxy

Currently I have access to the NGINX variables `$bytes_sent` and `$bytes_received` that are trivially provided on the http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html documentation page. I believe these only provide half the story I am interested in.

What is not made clear is how these variables interact when measured in conjunction with `proxy_pass http://$site_ip:$site_port$request_uri;`

Is there some way I can calculate the 4 cases of bandwidth I am interested in without modification to NGINX? I am able to use computational solutions if such a thing could be written via the lua hooks provided by OpenResty.

Thanks!